# Is there a way to step through HTML rendering?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application with Visual Studio 2010 Premium, as I run the application I want to be able to step through the HTML rendering as it happens.

Example: If the page has 3 text boxes on it, after the 1st text box is rendered, I want to be able to pause the browser, inspect the HTML, continue the HTML rendering, pause after the 2nd text box is rendered, inspect the HTML, then finish rendering the 3rd text box and rest of the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. The HTML is generated on the server side and sent to the client all together. Unless you have any javascript created elements you can't see the page being rendered on the client.

Comment: There's no way to pause the client as each object gets rendered?